# Python Multi-threading - How to kill all child threads when one of them raise an exception or failed

Tags: python, multithreading, multitasking

Depending on the needs of the program, I used multi-threads within a sub-thread for parallel tasking. In this *"deep"* multi-threading, potential problems such as timeouts and failures may be encountered.

I would like to ask, how to kill all child threads (known as *"deep"* multi-threading above) when one of them raise an exception or failed.

Comment: _how to kill_ if you ask if there is any mechanism, that does that, answer is: there is none (unless sys calls do it by themselves, but that's platform dependant). If you ask how to implement: something like [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or other pub/sub implementations will do.

Comment: How do you know if/when a thread has failed due to timeout or exception? Show us a code fragment that demonstrates your issue [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be trying to kill threads.

If a thread needs to terminate because of some unrelated condition then it needs to [somehow] be notified. You just need a "flag" that's accessible to all threads.

Here's a pattern that you could adapt. It requires that each thread checks the "flag" from time to time.

The "flag" in this case is a list that contains a single arbitrary value. The run condition is true if the list is not empty.

If a problem arises in one thread it should just clear the run list. Thus all other threads will terminate.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def process(run):
    while run:
        sleep(1) # do work
        if randint(1, 50) == 25: # simulate failure
            print("Failing")
            run.clear()
    print("Ending")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run = [None]
    threads = [Thread(target=process, args=(run,)) for _ in range(10)]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

You could make this slightly simpler by using a global variable if you're that way inclined